# the data could not be read because it isn't in the correct format iOS9.1 in iPhone6 with AFNetworking Library

Tags: ios, ios9, afnetworking-2, iphone-6, ios9.1

I am using AFNetworking Library as HTTP client for my Application. I am getting following error on iOS9.1 in iPhone 6 while verifying OTP.

I checked about the error on web but it is not occuring during build in XCode, it is occurring at runtime.

Thanks in advance[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tbyHK.jpg)

Comment: Provide the relevant parts of your code.

Comment: The error was reported in Apple Review. We couldn't  able reproduce it at our side

Comment: Still, provide the relevant parts of your code. Also check server logs if you have access to them.

Comment: Thanks jcaron . I have checked server logs and we are now solving issue.